# What is the Range of this Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find the range of Linear Transformation

$T(v) = Av$ where

$A$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & -2 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$

Now, this $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix so  we can consider it as a Linear Transformation from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$

Now, Rank $A$  = $2$ = Rank$T$

So, By rank nullity Theorem,

Rank$T$ = $2$ and Nullity$T$ =1

Since Rank$T$  = dimension of Range$T$

so, Range of $T$ is $\mathbb{R^2}$, However the answer given to me

is Range  = Plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Can anyone please check my solution and tell my errors ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos :Thank you for the quick response!